# Jmeter 2.13 shutdown issue in distributed non-gui mode

Tags: load, jmeter, load-testing

I generate load with new jmeter 2.13 in distributed non-gui mode and try to stop it with shutdown.cmd -- and it doesn't work.

I see in console "Command: shutdown received from /127.0.0.1" -- but load is still going after it.

In jmeter 2.12 it works ok, only sometimes you need to send second shutdown.
Does anybody know the solution or get the same problem?

It's really tiresome to interrupt tests with ctrl+c--and then manually kill/restart all jmeter-servers on remote nodes.

My environment: master host --  windows7, slave nodes -- windowsXP

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add some more information? How you start the jmeter server for example. I have not had the same problem, but then on the other hand I usually just do a "killall -9 java" when I want to shut down my jmeter servers :)

Answer (score 0):

They only time that I've encountered similar issues when the Jmeter process died on at least one load generator. The Controller has no way of knowing that this has happened and waits forever. Even when you send a shutdown command, it won't get its 'last batch' from the LGs, so it keeps waiting.

You mention having to kill and restart your load generators- obviously, if the lg procs are still running, they didn't die this way. If you're simply starting the process again, try spreading your load over more load generators.